# GPU hangs on initialization when trying to restart runtime

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm stuck in a frustrating loop trying to use the tensorflow estimator API.
When I try to restart my GPU instance, my notebook hangs on initialization.
[image: hanging cell when trying to restart kernel]
If I exit the notebook, or switch runtime to CPU and back to GPU again, and try to connect to my instance, I says the instance is busy.
[image: busy cell when trying to reopen notebook or switch back to GPU instance]
If I switch my runtime to no GPU and restart, the runtime initializes fine, but if I then try and reset the runtime to GPU, the notebook again says it is busy running what I assume to be a hanging GPU task.

So restarting the runtime, exiting the notebook, and switching the runtime to CPU and back to GPU do not seem to help with freeing/restarting the GPU backend.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Please share a notebook that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To reset your backend, select the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.

[image]